# Why cout statement is not executing in passing pointer to function?

Tags: c++

The cout statement in function call swap is not executing. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
  cout << "Value Swapped" << endl;
}

int main() {
  int x = 400, y = 100;
  swap(x, y);
  cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have expected below output:

```
Value Swapped
x = 100 y = 400
```

But the output I have got is:

```
x = 100 y = 400
```

Comment: I have expected below output:

Value Swapped
x = 100 y = 400

But the output I have got is: 
x = 100 y = 400

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, to confirm, that your function is called instead of `std::swap`? 2) Related: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) 3) "_I have expected below output ..._" Please provide such information in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: your `swap` function treats arguments as addresses while you are passing integers. that's not the only problem though

Comment: You are actually calling `std::swap`. Don't use `using namespace`...

Comment: General debugging note: When you get an inexplicable mystery bug, `using namespace std` should be one of the first things to go.

Comment: `s/When you get an inexplicable mystery bug, //`  :)  Seriously, if you hate typing `std::cout` that much, just say `using std::cout;`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not seeing "Value swapped" because your swap function never gets called. Instead, you're calling `std::swap<int>`.

If you hadn't said `using namespace std;`, you'd have found out that your `swap` function is being passed integers, but was expecting pointers. Reason #1 not to use `using namespace std;` -- you can easily end up not calling what you think you are. :)

Comment: *'passed integers, but was expecting pointers'* – that results in a compilation error already...

Comment: @Aconcagua it does, unless there's another overload that matches, which is the case once OP spilled `::std` into `::` ;)

Comment: @Quentin *'If you hadn't said'* – so in *this* context, no other overload any more...

Comment: @Aconcagua I think the three of us are agreeing here. Remove `using namespace std;`, call the expected function, get a compile-time error because the argument types don't match, find the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

your function swap is expecting pointers as arguments, but you are passing integers. So instead of calling your function, it's calling the c++ swap function. To better understand this, change the function name 'swap' to any other name like 'swapp' and you'll see this error:

```
invalid conversion from int to int*
```

write swap(&x, &y) and you'll get your desired output

Comment: Thanks @Sudip sarker.

Answer (score 0):

Consider choosing a unique enough identifier name such that there will not be a conflict with a `namespace` identifier (as in `std::swap`). If you can't choose the name of your identifier, `put it inside of a namespace`.

Secondly, if the compiler does not enforce the function declaration that you state, you should manually check to see that you passed the variables correctly (i.e., `&x` and `&y` instead of `x` and `y`).

Answer (score 0):

`using namespace std` imports another equally named function from namespace `std` into global namespace, so you end up in having two overloads:

```
swap(int&, int&); // from std; actually a template instantiation
swap(int*, int*);
```

You call `swap` as

```
swap(x, y);
```

Now consider: Which are the types of `x` and `y`, are they pointers? So decide yourself, which overload will get called?

If you hadn't imported the second overload via `using namespace std`, which generally is considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) anyway (well, you got a victim of the pitfalls of right away...), you would have ended up in a compilation error instead (integers aren't converted to pointers implicitly!).

To get *your* function called, you need to make pointers from:

```
swap(&x, &y);
//   ^   ^
```

Actually, that would have worked even with the imported namespace (despite of being bad practice), as the imported overload is a template, yours an ordinary function, thus yours is considered the more specialised overload and thus will be preferred.